# Steganography on audio/video with Python

Tags: python, video-processing, steganography, audio-processing

I want to do message embedding in audio/video files using Python. Does anyone have information about some libraries I can use for bit manipulation in audio/video ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of [audio-related modules](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio) on the python website (as well as [this list](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic)), and there are other questions dealing with video [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220866/best-video-manipulation-library-for-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003376/python-video-framework) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832116/python-video-library).  From looking further into it, GStreamer appears to have support for both audio and video editing, and also seems quite favored.

Also, if you're interested in steganography in images as well, there is the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

Answer (score 0):

I read a article on

http://hareenlaks.blogspot.com/2010/05/what-is-steganography.html

it describes message embedding in audio/video files .